# how to convert hours to days

Tags: sql, time

I have an hours value that I would like to convert to days, such as 1.97 hours to days or 26.50 hours to days. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to do a simple and standard unit conversion - just divide by 24

```
Select 1.94 as hour, 1.94/24 as days
```